# Chrome ADB extension not working on Debian 7

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adb

I'm using debian 7 amd64. I can't connect my android phone to chrome in order to do remote debugging .

The checklist in chrome developers site is this

1. An Android phone or tablet with Chrome for Android 28 or later
       installed from Google Play.
2. A USB cable to plug in your device.
       (Windows users will also need to install an appropriate USB device
       driver.)
3. Chrome 28 or later installed on your development machine.
4. The ADB Chrome extension installed on your development
   machine

I've done all this. But when I press the 'Start ADB' button nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althought the chrome extension button still don't work, I'm able to inspect the connected devices via

```
chrome://inspect/
```

Comment: This is our preferred way of getting access to the devices now.

Answer (score 1):

Does the command-line `adb` work? If not, chances are you haven't set up your `udev` rules correctly. Your current user must have full permissions to the USB device your phone is on.

Here's how my `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` is set up:

```
# Nexus 4
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee2", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
# Galaxy Nexus
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

You will need to add the correct vendor/product IDs for your specific phone, of course. And add yourself to the `plugdev` group.

Then, you need to run `sudo service udev reload` to apply the rule changes. You should be good to go after that.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I haven't installed this.  Should I install something?

Comment: No, just use `lsusb` to find out what the vendor/product ID for your phone is (you may need to enable `adb` for your phone first, if it's the type that uses a different product ID for `adb`), then add the appropriate entry to your `udev` rules (see my example).

Comment: The file 51-android.rules doesn't exists. I've created one. The product Id/Vendor is the same as Galaxy Nexus. I tried again but it still doens't work.

Comment: Good. Then make sure you're in the `plugdev` group (you may need to relogin if you weren't in that group at the start of your login session), and then run `sudo service udev reload`, and you should be good to go. You may also need to unplug your phone and plug it back in.

Comment: I've checked I'm in the plugdev group, but still no luck. Do I need this package 'android-tools-adb' to make this work ?

Comment: I've never looked at the Chrome extension, so I don't know if it needs it. I just use command-line `adb`, myself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40209/discussion-between-user1532587-and-chris-jester-young)